# Conversion of JSON object of objects using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to covert the following JSON which contains an object of json objects into a Java object on Android using gson.fromJson(json, packageClass), however, I am having trouble figuring out what the structure of my java package class should be.

```
{
"package": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "my test description",
    "contents": {
        "product1": {
            "description": "my product 1"
        },
        "product 2": {
            "description": "my product 2"
        },
        "product 3": {
            "description": "my product 3"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a class where the field names match the name of the JSON fields:

```
public class Entry {
  Map<String, Object> package; 
}
```

This is very basic and minimal.

Another option is to create the classes:

```
public class Entry {
  Package package; 
}

public class Package {
  String version;
  String description:
  Map<String, Product> contents; 
}


public class Product {
  String description:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use gson.fromJson to convert json string into bean class object